# R: assigning objects to vector in loop

Tags: r, for-loop, variable-assignment

I'm generating regressions of 30 subpopulations in a for-loop and assigning them to successive elements of a list (matrix?).  It seems like only the first component of each regression is making it into the list.  The simple version goes like this:

```
i <- 30
num30 <- with(gapMeans, lm(DHt[Gap==i] ~ Time[Gap==i]))
```

Works just as I want.  The loop version goes:

```
gmRegs <- NULL
for (i in 1:30){ 
     gmRegs[i] <- with(gapMeans,
                        if(Ht[Gap==i][1] > 1){
                            lm(DHt[Gap==i] ~ Time[Gap==i])
                        } else {NULL}
                 )}
```

That runs correctly but:

```
num30

# Call:
# lm(formula = DHt[Gap == i] ~ Time[Gap == i])
#
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  Time[Gap == i]  
#      24.56874        -0.01546  

gmRegs[30]
# [[1]]
# (Intercept) Time[Gap == i] 
# 24.56874082    -0.01546019
```

And `str()` describes `num30` as a list of 13 while `gmRegs[30`] is a list of 1, and when I try to do `abline(reg=gmRegs[30])` it won't.  So it seems like my assignment is doing only `thing1[1] <- thing2[1]`, or something to that effect -- I just can't figure out how to properly box up the `lm()` object to all fit in the list slot.

Comment: what sort of object is gmRegs? If it is a list, you can extract elements with gmRegs[[1]]

Comment: `with(gapMeans, lm(DHt[Gap==i] ~ Time[Gap==i]))` can be written more clearly as `lm(DHt ~ Time, data  = gapMeans, subset = Gap == i)`

Comment: @RichardTelford gmRegs starts out null; sorry; forgot to put that line; edited.  And true about the clarifying -- I just wound up at this by banging away, so this is the thing as I've got it.  Also just edited out that I had c(with(...)), which was a bit from another fruitless attempt.

Comment: make gmRegs a list `gmRegs <- list()` then your code should work. Extract with `gmRegs[[1]]`

Comment: Lacks a reproducible example

Comment: @RichardScriven Only the horrible data is lacking -- which I withheld out of consideration.  But thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save an lm as an item to a list, the lm itself is a structured element in R. As you have noted, running `str(num30)` returns a list of 13 things. If you want to save each lm as an element in a list, you can do the following:

```
# generate random data
response <- runif(90,0,1)
time <- runif(90,10,20)
gap <- rep(1:30,3)

gapMeans <- data.frame(gap,response,time)
```

Now, `head(gapMeans)` returns

```
  gap  response     time
1   1 0.6809973 12.66655
2   2 0.5473042 11.73821
3   3 0.6095777 18.96527
4   4 0.3081830 15.62343
5   5 0.1640612 13.42454
6   6 0.8473997 12.83730
```

As Richard pointed above, you can rewrite your with call as the following lm:

```
num30 <- lm(response[gap==30] ~ time[gap==30], data = gapMeans)
```

Now for your loop you can simply write the following:

```
gmRegs <- NULL

for(i in 1:30){
  gmRegs[[i]] <- lm(response[gap==i] ~ time[gap==i], data= gapMeans)
}
```

Now each element of `gmRegs`, accessed via `gmRegs[[30]]` is itself a lm object.

```
plot(gapMeans$time[gapMeans$gap==30], gapMeans$response[gapMeans$gap==30], xlab = 'time', ylab = 'response')
abline(gmRegs[[30]]$coefficients, col = "red")
```

[image: Example plot, since I can't embed images yet]

Comment: Thanks Michael; I see the part I was missing (other than clean syntax...) was to address the thing with [[]].  I've been RTFMing for weeks now, but that's the kind of thing that's still tough to pick up.